# LINQ query to find items in a list containing substring elements from a second list

Tags: c#, linq, substring

I am trying to list all elements from the first list where it contains a substring equal to all elements from the second list

**First list:**

```
C:\Folder\Files_01026666.pdf
C:\Folder\Files_01027777.pdf
C:\Folder\Files_01028888.pdf
C:\Folder\Files_01029999.pdf
```

**Second list:**

```
01027777
01028888
```

**List result should be:**

```
C:\Folder\Files_01027777.pdf
C:\Folder\Files_01028888.pdf
```

the closer that I got was with `.Intersect()` but both string-element should be equals

```
List<string> resultList = firstList.Select(i => i.ToString()).Intersect(secondList).ToList();

List<string> resultList = firstList.Where(x => x.Contains(secondList.Select(i=>i).ToString()));

List<string> resultList = firstList.Where(x => x == secondList.Select(i=>i).ToString());
```

I know I can do this another way but I'd like to do it with LINQ.
I have looked at other queries but I can find a close comparison to this with Linq. Any ideas or anywhere you can point me to would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`EndsWith()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-6.0) with [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=net-6.0#system-io-path-getfilenamewithoutextension(system-string)), as strings in the secondList are not entire file names.

```
var result = firstList
    .Where(path => secondList.Any(fileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path).EndsWith(fileName)));
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mpubob)

Comment: I just edited my post, the second list is not a path, just a regular string, there's no ".pdf" extension

Comment: Is `File_` and `.pdf` is constant ?

Comment: ```Files_``` and ```.pdf``` are indeed constants

Comment: @Ekel, I added fiddle example you can try it online

Comment: @Ekel, any updates on your question? did my answer helped you to solve your problem?

Comment: thank you it's working great, but it wasn't working until I saw a bad formatting on my firstList strings that your solution brought up

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = list1.Where(t=>Regex.IsMatch(t,String.Join("|",list2.ToArray()))));
```

Seems to work for lists of strings. Using Regex can be problem in LINQ. This won't work in Linq2SQL for example.